# Is there a way of storing color hex codes in variables similar to SASS in React-Native?

Tags: variables, colors, sass, react-native

I have colours in my React Native project and I was wondering if I can store the colours in variables similar to how you would using SASS - naming them and saving them in a separate file. Below is an example of my styles for some input fields.

```
module.exports = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput:{
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color: '#666',
    height: 60,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
  }
});
```

I want to know if I can do something similar to this (SASS):

`$cornflower-blue: #6195ED;` (with other colour variables in separate file)

```
article {
  background-color: $cornflower-blue;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can literally use variables in JavaScript.

colors.js

```
export const cornFlowerBlue = '#6195ED';
```

when you want to use it

```
import {cornFlowerBlue} from './colors';
...
module.exports = StyleSheet.create({
  article {
    backgroundColor: cornFlowerBlue,
  }
});
```

EDIT: $cornflower-blue will not work as a name because `-` is reserved for subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#global-variables) that supports global and local variables like SASS:

```
// app entry: set global variables
EStyleSheet.build({
  textColor: '#0275d8'
});

// component: use global variables
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: '$textColor'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a settings file where I import any constants across my app

```
'use strict';

var settings = {
    siteURL: 'http://www.website.com',
    green: '#80bc5a',
    lightGreen: '#c0dead',
    lightGrey: '#f1efeb',
    darkGrey: '#54575a',
    brown: '#867f75',
};

var settings = require('./Settings')
module.exports = settings;

var { siteURL, green } = settings
```